# How to clip an Asymptote parametric surface to a ball?

Tags: asymptote

I have a parametric surface like:

```
surface s = surface(F, (0, 0), (2pi, 2pi), 60, 65, Spline);
```

where $F(u, v) \in \mathbb{R}$. I want to clip it to a ball, e.g. the ball of radius one centered at the origin. In other words, I want to discard the part of the surface which is not in this ball ([motivation](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/MeshClipping.html)).

Comment: To my knowledge the only solution is to have a spherical parametrisation and then to do it  by yourself.